# Matrix multiplication with non-commuting objects (Quantum)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Given a matrix `A = {{0,a,a,0},{b,0,0,a},{b,0,0,a},{0,b,b,0}}`, where $a$ and $b$ do not commute, how do I calculate $A^2$ in Mathematica?

(Later on, I would like to generalise to calculate objects of the type $e^A$.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[0, a_] := 0;
NonCommutativeMultiply[a_, 0] := 0;

A = {{0, a, a, 0}, {b, 0, 0, a}, {b, 0, 0, a}, {0, b, b, 0}};
Table[
 Sum[A[[i, k]] ** A[[k, j]], {k, 1, 4}]
 , {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

> {{2 a ** b, 0, 0, 2 a ** a}, {0, a ** b + b ** a, a ** b + b ** a, 0}, {0, a ** b + b ** a, a ** b + b ** a, 0}, {2 b ** b, 0, 0, 2 b ** a}}

Comment: The `Table` statement could be accomplished with `Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, A, A]`

Comment: Ah very neat! Go ahead and post it!